# Check the convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty{2^{-\sqrt{k}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Check the convergence of $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty{2^{-\sqrt{k}}}$$
I have tried all other tests (ratio test, integral test, root test, etc.) but none of them got me anywhere.
Pretty sure the way to do it is to check the convergence by comparison, but not 
sure how.

Comment: It seems to me that the integral test works. Why did it fail?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are $(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$ distinct $k$ with $n\le \sqrt k<n+1$.
For these $k$, $2^{-\sqrt k}\le 2^{-n}$. So, your sum compares to
$\sum_n (2n+1)2^{-n}$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$2^{-\sqrt{k}} = e^{-\sqrt{k}\ln 2}$$ while $$\frac{1}{k^2} = e^{-2\ln k}.$$ Since $\sqrt{k} \ln 2 > 2\ln k$ for $k$ big enough,* you can conclude by comparison with the $p$-series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$.

> *One can check it holds for all $k\geq 256$.

Comment: It is clear that eventually the desired inequality but how did you figure out that it holds for $k\geq 256$? Sorry if I am missing something simple. Really like this solution though +1

Comment: @qbert It is not needed for the conclusion (knowing it'll hold "after a while" is enough). If you want to check how to get an explicit bound, study the function $f$ defined by $f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\ln x}$. It is increasing for $x>e^2$, so you only need to find a single value such that $f(x) > \frac{2}{\ln 2}$. Then, whether you do it by trial-and-error or systematic study of $f$ is up to you. I personally cheated and used Mathematica to find a value, and then checked it.

Comment: of course, I was just curious. Thanks!

Comment: @qbert You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Referring to Miguel's comment on integral test:
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{\sqrt{x}}}dx 
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^t}\cdot 2tdt\\
&=2\left(t\cdot \frac{-2^{-t}}{\ln{2}}\bigg{|}_{0}^{\infty}+\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{-t}}{\ln{2}}dt\right)\\
&=2\left(-\frac{2^{-t}}{\ln^2{2}}\bigg{|}_{0}^{\infty}\right)=\frac{2}{\ln^2{2}}\\&<\infty.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your post (using an `align` environment) to fix the alignment of the equations. Let me know if that looks alright.

Comment: @ClementC, thank you. It looks better.