# Closed from for "geometric sums in $\sqrt n$ "? $\sum{a^{-\sqrt n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is known of sums in forms$$\sum_{n =1}^{\infty}{a^{-\sqrt n}}$$ or at least similar such sums. How do you find a closed form for one, if there exists one or maybe the generating function for the sum cut off at  the $x^{th}$ partial sum? Thanks

Comment: You don't. ${}$

Comment: $a $ must be $>1$.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima I can see how that's necessary, but is it enough?

Comment: For convergence?  Comparison test with $\sum 1/n^2$ should do.  Or integral test.

Comment: Or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2414492/75808 . But that won't help you to get a closed-form, which, alas, is something you should probably forget about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bound your summation between $ \frac{2 (\log (a)+1)}{a \log ^2(a)}\leq \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty } a^{-\sqrt{n}}\leq \frac{2}{\log ^2(a)}$ but a **Closed Form** is very very hard to derive.

Comment: By "very very hard," you mean "unknown"? If so, that's a strong understatement.

Comment: @ClementC. both sentences tells the truth.

Comment: Indeed, but only one gives hope, the second essentially states "there is none."

Comment: @ClementC. i cant disagree.